# MySQL query to return multiple summed columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I have the following data in my SQL table.

```
uid    user    category    count    date
--------------------------------------------------
1      henry   RED         4        2013-05-01
2      john    BLUE        3        2013-05-01
3      alice   RED         5        2013-05-01
4      eric    GREEN       2        2013-05-02
5      eric    BLUE        2        2013-05-02
6      john    RED         3        2013-05-02
7      henry   GREEN       2        2013-05-02
8      eric    RED         3        2013-05-03
9      john    BLUE        5        2013-05-03
```

I would like a query that gives me back the following data

```
category    2013-05-01    2013-05-02    2013-05-03
---------------------------------------------------
RED         9             3             3
BLUE        3             2             5
GREEN       0             4             0
```

I can get one column of data with the following query, but I do not know how to get multiple columns grouped as shown above. I'd like to have one query that my PHP renders instead of looping through each date.

```
SELECT category, SUM(count) 
FROM dbtable 
WHERE date='2013-05-01' 
GROUP BY category;
```

Is this possible? Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
  category,
  SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2013-05-01' THEN count END) AS `2013-05-01`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2013-05-02' THEN count END) AS `2013-05-02`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2013-05-03' THEN count END) AS `2013-05-03`
FROM dbtable
GROUP BY category
```

Comment: That worked. Is there any general form for this where I could pick a start date and end date, and then group it by day or week?

Comment: Probably so, but could you kindly post that as a different question? The week grouping can be a bit involved, and there's the question of what a week is - Sun-Sat? Mon-Sun? etc. In addition, having a new question will get you fresh views and more community input in case I can't answer it.