# MySQL query to return multiple summed and grouped columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, case

Part 2 to the question asked here -

[MySQL query to return multiple summed columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323507/mysql-query-to-return-multiple-summed-columns)

I have the following data in my SQL table. Imagine that there are many more rows spanning years worth of data.

```
uid    user    category    count    date
--------------------------------------------------
1      henry   RED         4        2013-04-01
2      john    BLUE        3        2013-04-11
4      eric    GREEN       2        2013-04-22
3      alice   RED         5        2013-05-01
5      eric    BLUE        2        2013-05-12
6      john    RED         3        2013-05-23
7      henry   GREEN       2        2013-06-03
8      eric    RED         3        2013-06-08
9      john    BLUE        5        2013-07-11
... (more) ...
```

I would like a query that gives me back the following data, grouped in columns according to the date. I know how to use the GROUP BY command to group data into rows. But I am not sure how to do it by columns.

```
category    May 2013     April 2013  ... (more)
------------------------------------
RED         8            4           
BLUE        2            3     
GREEN       0            2
```

I realize there are probably a lot of options, as far as using date and time functions. I'm just looking more for the basic structure of how to set up the logic for SQL to give me an arbitrary number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

You should try summing by cases (and sum 0 when not true). Like the following:

```
SELECT 
   ...
   SUM(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN ... AND ... THEN 'count' ELSE 0 END) as 'May 2013',
   SUM(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN ... AND ... THEN 'count' ELSE 0 END) as 'April 2013',
   etc.
FROM ...,
GROUP BY category
```

Comment: Could you have something like a for loop where you look at the months between now and 3 months ago?

Comment: In your solution the sums get broken up by category. Can be subdivide that again by MONTH(date)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use Procedural Language My SQL to looping the month/year.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
  category,
  SUM(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-06-01' THEN count ELSE 0 END) AS 'May 2013',
  SUM(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-05-01' THEN count ELSE 0 END) AS 'April 2013',
  ... (more)   
FROM dbtable
GROUP BY category
```